# MS Access VBA: Return to login form if login fails

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access, error-handling

I'm working on a login form using MS Access 2010 and VBA. I have been able to create a message that pops up if a user enters a user/password combination that fails when those credentials are passed to a function that tries to log in to an ODBC database connection. The login form then closes.

What I would like to do is have the application return the focus to the login form and ask the user to try the login again. Below is the current login error I have adapted from the info at this URL:
http://allenbrowne.com/ser-23a.html

```
ErrorHandler:
    strMsg = "An unexpected situation arose in your program." & vbCrLf & _
        "Please write down the following details:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        "Unable to sign in because of Error: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf &     Err.Description
    MsgBox strMsg, vbCritical
    Exit Function
```

Does anyone have a hint or reference on how to get that behavior using VBA?

Thanks for any help,
jrdevdba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After "msgBox strMsg, vbCritical" in your error handler add the following:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "LoginFormName"
```

Then in the Form_Open event of the login form put

```
me.TextBoxName.SetFocus
```

You'll need to change "LoginFormName" and "TextBoxName" to the name of your forms.  I'd be curious as to why the login form is closing but I'd need to see the rest of your code for that.

Comment: Thanks! I think the login form is closing because I exit the function above and also have code to close the form in the calling procedure.